# TS2339:(TS) Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'

Tags: angular

**My code which i tried to impliment , it shows 'catch' does not exist.**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../Model/User';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';  

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  headers: HttpHeaders;
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'content-type': 'application/json' });
  }
  GetUser(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get(environment.apiAddress + '/user').catch(err => Observable.throw(err));
  }
}
```

Comment: First you should subscribe then catch anything or use rxjs pipe

Answer (score 1):

You need to pipe the Observable.

```
GetUser(): Observable<User[]> {
  return this.httpClient.get(environment.apiAddress + '/user').pipe(
    catchError(err => throw(err)),
  );
}
```